# How do I include a custom command with the MapReduceIndexerTool in Oozie?

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera, oozie, hadoop-yarn

I want to create an Oozie workflow that would use the [MapReduceIndexerTool](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-0-0/Search/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_mapreduceindexertool.html) to take my data and index it. I've managed to get it working using a Shell action, which calls my script to execute the following command:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-*-job.jar \
org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool \
-D 'mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx500m' \
--morphline-file morphline.conf \
--output-dir hdfs://cloudera1:8020/user/nicolas/outdir \
--verbose --go-live --zk-host cloudera2:2181/solr  \
--collection Test_Collection hdfs:///user/nicolas/indir
```

It finds all the files and directories it needs, and the workflow will finish successfully. However, I would like to add my custom Morphlines command to modify some of the data. I have been following the [kitesdk guide](http://kitesdk.org/docs/current/kite-morphlines/morphlinesReferenceGuide.html) to do just that. I packaged my code into a jar and uploaded it to ***hdfs://cloudera1:8020/user/nicolas/custom-command.jar*** through the Hue File Browser. I've also updated my ***morphline.conf*** so that I import my package, and use my command. If I just include the file in my workflow, the following error occurs:

```
Error: org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineCompilationException: No command builder registered for name: tweakData ...
```

I'm assuming that the MapReduceIndexerTool is having trouble finding my jar. So, I decided to add the --libjars parameter to my script:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-*-job.jar \
org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool \
--libjars hdfs://cloudera1:8020/user/nicolas/custom-command.jar ...
```

When I do that, a different error occurs:

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException
as:yarn (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
hdfs://cloudera1:8020/tmp/hadoop-yarn/mapred/staging/yarn1033647717/.staging/job_local1033647717_0001/libjars/custom-command.jar
```

**TD;DR** How to I include the jar for my custom Morphlines command so it is found by Oozie / YARN?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the jars to the lib sub-directory of the oozie wf HDFS directory or add the jar to the  tag in oozie shell action.

Answer (score 0):

--libjars requires a file on the local file system (rather than an HDFS file).

Comment: That makes sense. When I do include put a local file path, I need to have my jar copied over all of my nodes or else it will have trouble finding it. Is there an easy way to do that, especially in a large cluster?

Comment: It is easy - hadoop already automatically copies the --libjars from the local filesystem to the remote nodes that run the mapreduce tasks (via the hadoop distributed cache).

Comment: All the jar files required by my MapReduce are present at local file system of the hadoop nodes (/home/ubuntu/libs/). During the execution these are referred as hdfs://<ip>:<port>:/home/ubuntu/libs and not from the local file system of the node. How can I resolve it?